# Package debian with contents from target/classes using Maven

Tags: maven, debian, packaging

I want to package a debian with files from maven generated target/classes directory of my project. Is there a way that I can pick those files before debian push?

Comment: Explain better  what you mean. Do you want to create a .deb package? Do you want it to be installanble in Debian systems?

Comment: I want debian to package contents from target folder. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to use maven resources plugin to generate build info into target/classes which also writes the info to the property file packaged into debian